# How to enter "desc" parameter in postgresql function?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I need to enter value for direction of sort in a function, but how to do it?

Tried like that, but this doesn't work of course.

```
create or replace function invest_ideas 
(order_by_direction varchar default 'desc')
```

```
create or replace function invest_ideas 
(order_by_direction RECORD default desc)
```

in query line looks like that:

```
order by creation_time order_by_direction
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
ORDER BY id * CASE WHEN order_by_direction='desc' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END
```

For a *life* test see:  [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/YN1dz9Hu)

Comment: This will not work for timestamps as they can not be multiplied by an integer. Intervals however can. So `ORDER BY (creation_time - CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) * CASE WHEN order_by_direction = 'desc' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END`

Comment: @Stefanov.sm: And for VARCHAR (or CHAR) , the same is **true**.

Comment: Oh, sure. I mentioned timestamps only because `creation_time` that OP asks about is most probably one.

Answer (score -2):

Use [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) with [format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT):

```
create table created_at(creation_time timestamp);
insert into created_at values (now()), (now() - interval '1 day'), (now() + interval '1 day');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.order_fnc(order_by_direction character varying DEFAULT 'desc'::character varying)
 RETURNS SETOF timestamp without time zone
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    IF order_by_direction in ('asc', 'desc') THEN
        RETURN QUERY
            EXECUTE format(
            'SELECT creation_time FROM created_at ORDER BY creation_time  %s',
            order_by_direction);
    ELSE
        RAISE EXCEPTION $$Must use either 'asc' or 'desc'$$;
    END IF;
END;
$function$


select order_fnc('asc');
         order_fnc          
----------------------------
 10/06/2023 14:04:25.123912
 10/07/2023 14:04:25.123912
 10/08/2023 14:04:25.123912

select order_fnc();
         order_fnc          
----------------------------
 10/08/2023 14:04:25.123912
 10/07/2023 14:04:25.123912
 10/06/2023 14:04:25.123912
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection. Pass the sort direction as a `boolean`.

Comment: or simply `case when order_by_direction = 'asc' then return query <the query> order by creation_time; when order_by_direction = 'desc' then return query <the query> order by creation_time desc; else raise error <error text>; end case;`